# Put AJAX Response in HTML format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've AJAX response which needs to be rendered in HTML setup in PHP file. I'm confused regarding how to render it as there are multiple data in AJAX response and each of them must be put in specific places in html

for example AJAX response has two(or n) objects like this:

```
0:Object
     id: "111"
     Name: "abc"
1:Object
     id: "112"
     Name: "xyz"
```

Then, There already would be two(or n) divs with `user` class in HTML

```
<div class='user'>
    <div class='userId'> 
        <div class='usernm'>  </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='user'>
    <div class='userId'> 
        <div class='usernm'> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I need is put those response values in this divs like this:

```
<div class='user'>
    <div class='userId'> 111
        <div class='usernm'> abc </div>
    </div>
</div>

 <div class='user'>
    <div class='userId'> 112
        <div class='usernm'> xyz</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm lost as to how can I achieve that on AJAX Success here using **jQuery**:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/url/goes/here',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
            console.log(value); //this outputs response as Objects shown above                   
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Why you put 2 `div` before the response. Create `div` at the place when currently you wrote `console.log();` and append it to the parent `div`

Comment: @KinjalMistry I'm not allowed to create div in response, I only have to put the data

Comment: Check Madalin ivascu's answer. And if you don't allow to create let me know the reason. Why you are not allowed?

Comment: @KinjalMistry I'm told that this AJAX req is to called multiple times (probably every 1sec), so in that case it would increase the load if I create the html content in response every sec. so instead, i've to only append the new data that response has

Comment: Is your response count fix? I mean to say every time you have only 2 records on your response? or there is a case to get differ count of records?

Comment: I've used two only as an example, there may be n response count

Comment: So you must have to create your HTML during the rendering data in javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `append` function in your loop to add the elements to the page

```
$('body').append('<div class="user">
    <div class="userId"> '+value.id+'
        <div class="usernm">'+value.name+'</div>
    </div>
</div>');//note change the body element to your desired parent element
```

if you only need to put the data do the following:

```
success: function(data) {
     $('.userId').each(function(key, value){
                $(value).prepend(data[key].id);   
                $(value).find('.usernm').text(data[key].name);              
            });
}
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/gf32wd7L/1/

Comment: Sir, by any means, would it possible to only append the data and not the whole HTML tags?

Comment: see my second part of the answer

Comment: the second part should go in the AJAX Success part, inside `$.each(data, function(key, value){ HERE }` ?

Comment: so only inside success?

Comment: hi, I'm stuck with something very simple..can you please have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40035148/ajax-response-using-html5-data-attribute

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: '/url/goes/here',
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data) {
       $.each(data, function(key, value) {
         $('<div/>', {
           'class': 'user'
         }).append(
           $('<div/>', {
             'class': 'userId'
           }).text(this.id).append(
             $('<div/>', {
               text: 'usernme'
             }).text(this.Name)
           });
       });
     }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way, Use if it is convenient,

Let us say ur HTML,

```
<div class="append-div"></div>
```

Your JSON,

```
{
"Objects":[
    {
        "id": "111",
        "name": "abc"
    },
    {
        "id": "112",
        "name": "xyz"
    }
 ]
}
```

The JS,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'json.js',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        var userDiv = "";
        $.each(data.Objects, function(key, value){
            console.log(value); //this outputs response as Objects shown above
            userDiv += '<div class="user"><div class="userId">' + value.id + '</div>' + value.name + '</div>';
        });

        $(".append-div").append(userDiv);  // Append the results
    }
});
});
```