# AJAX response using HTML5 data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I've a working env where I'm using AJAX response to fill in HTML elements.

for example AJAX response has two(or n) objects like this:

```
0:Object
     id: "111"
     Name: "abc"
1:Object
     id: "112"
     Name: "xyz"
```

Then, There already would be two(or n) divs with `user` class and HTML5 `data-user` containing the **id** in HTML

```
<div class='user' data-user='111'>
    <div class='userId'data-userId='111> </div>
     <div class='usernm' data-user='usernm'> </div>
</div>

<div class='user' data-user='112'>
    <div class='userId'data-userId='112> </div>
     <div class='usernm' data-user='usernm'> </div>
</div>
```

What I need is put those response values in this divs like this:

```
<div class='user' data-user='111'>
    <div class='userId'data-userId='111> 111 </div>
     <div class='usernm' data-user='usernm'> abc </div>
</div>
 <div class='user' data-user='112'>
    <div class='userId'data-userId='112> 112 </div>
     <div class='usernm' data-user='usernm'> xyz </div>
</div>
```

What I'm currently doing (and is working) is using jQuery **find** (see below code) but now I'm suggested to put the responses using HTML5 `data-..` attribute. I can't get around it, if someone can help up with it..

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/url/goes/here',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
       $('.user').each(function(key, value){ //i need to remove .user and use data-user here (if possible)
            $(value).find('.userid').text(data[key].id); //i need to put values using data attr instead of find
            $(value).find('.usernm').text(data[key].name); //i need to put values using data attr instead of find              
       });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Data attributes are accessed by:

```
$(#id).data('userId');
```

or

```
$(#id).attr('data-userId');
```

and to set a value in that data attribute:

```
$(#id).data('userId', 'value');
```

or

```
$(#id).attr('data-userId', 'value');
```

Comment: since I've response time concern, I'm replacing using **find**  (hope I'm right), so for better speed what would be better - `attr` or `data`?

Comment: attr is a common method to access id, title etc and data for only for data attributes. So use as per your convenience.

Comment: `$('div[data-userId="'+data[key].id+'"]', data[key].id);`
something like this is possible?

Comment: jQuery's `data()` method doesnt **set** a `data-attribute`. It does store behind the scene a reference of the element and the data passed as value. `$(element).data('attr', 'value') element.getAttribute('data-attr')` will return `null`. Also, `element[data-attr]` CSS selector won't match the element. However, it can **get** data-attritbutes if no jQuery `data` were set.